# gRPC crashes with "Error starting a batch of operations: 8"

Tags: ios, objective-c, grpc

My app uses the Objective-C gRPC framework. Every so often, it crashes in the gRPC code with the error

> Error starting a batch of operations: 8

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you run your app under environment variables `GRPC_TRACE=all GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` and reproduce this issue?

Comment: Posting the crash stack trace would be helpful.